# Specify a Root Path of hosted app for script links in SharePoint hosted app?

Tags: custom-masterpage, sharepoint-hosted-app, scriptlink

I'm writing script reference in custom master page, and don't want to change the scripts for subfolder pages.

Is there a way to make the path relative to the root directory?

for example:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="**root**/style.css" />
```

Instead of **root** above, I want a default path there. Is there any way to do anything like this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

You can use :

```
<link href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/css/style.css%>" rel="stylesheet" runat ="server"/>
```